# Count cells that match and do not match some strings

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif

I have a google form feeding data into a spreadsheet and I'm trying to count responses based on string text. The possible responses in a column are
- "Yes. I love this"
- "No. I hate it"
- Random text

The third option is when response is neutral and people are free to fill i whatever they like. I have this formula counting Yes's and No's.

`=countif(F3:F35,"Yes. I love this") & " Yes, " & countif(F3:F35,"No. I hate it") & " No"`

What formula can I use for counting all other non-empty cells that aren't Yes or No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the total, remove:

1. blanks
2. yes's
3. no's

```
=33-COUNTBLANK(F3:F35)-COUNTIF(F3:F35,"Yes. I love this")-COUNTIF(F3:F35,"No. I hate it")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Count Column F, and then subtract it by the formula you already have.

Answer (score 0):

To count the non-empty cells that are not `Yes` or `No`,

```
=COUNTIFS(F3:F35,"<>Yes. I love this",F3:F35,"<>No. I hate it",A1:A4,"<>")
```